# How to render the infoPage.js page in a seperate window when the user click on handleClick function

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks, react-router

I would like to render the infoPage.js when the user clicks to handleClick function in react. Help Appreciated?

**infoPage.js**

```
import React from 'react'

export default function infoPage() {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1> this is info components</h1>
        </div>
    )
}
```

**App.js:**

```
<button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={handleClick}>{value.title}</button>
```

**Function:**

```
const handleClick = () => {
   const url = infoPage;
   window.open(url, '_blank');
 }
```

Comment: Can you explain in detail about your question !

Comment: I would like to render the react component when the user click to handleClick function which should render the infoPage.js

Comment: You want to open `infoPage` in new window when click on button right ?

Comment: can you set the route of the infoPage ?

Comment: Please forward me the working code. appreciate your help

Comment: pls tell me first can you access the `/infoPage` from browser ?

Comment: yes, /infoPage with data inside of it  in browser

Answer (score 0):

If you want to the `/infoPage` in new window, then try this code it's works.!

```
const handleClick = () => {
           window.open('/infoPage', '_blank', 'location=yes,height=570,width=520,scrollbars=yes,status=yes');
 }
```

Comment: InfoPage.js data not loading in new tab, not working if you have working code, I  appreciated your help

Comment: can you try to pass `'location=yes,height=570,width=520,scrollbars=yes,status=yes'` those parameter in `window.open` ?

Comment: thank you, tried it opened in new widow with infopage but not the data inside of it, i think i need to work with react-routor dom also but no idea how to implement on my project

Comment: If my answer helps you then accept it. :)